# Cayley–Hamilton theorem and the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$, an **invertible** matrix and $f_A(x)$ to be the characteristic polynomial. By Cayley–Hamilton theorem we know that $f_A(A) = 0$. More detailed:

$$0 = f_A(A) = a_0 + a_1A + \ldots + a_{n-1}A^{n-1} + A^n$$

Why is it true that there's an $i$ such that $0 \le i \lt n$ and

$$a_0 + \ldots + a_iA^i = 0$$

**The Exercise:**
Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, invertible. Show that $$A^{-1} \in \text{span}\left\{ I,A,\ldots , A^{n-1} \right\}$$

Can you interpret now the start of the proof?

Comment: And why do you think that this is true?

Comment: It's part of a proof I'm reading.

Comment: Actually now I've noticed that it says there's an $i$ such that $a_0 + a_1A + \ldots a_{i-1}A^{i-1} = 0$.

Comment: So how can $i$ be zero? Maybe that's a typo of the writer. Anyway, why is it true?

Comment: You can take $i = 0$ (unless $n = 0$, in which case I guess whatever you want to prove is obvious), and then $a_0 + a_1 + ... + a_{i-1} A^{i-1} = \left(\text{empty sum}\right) = 0$. What is the point of this exercise? Does the proof go on to choose the highest such $i$ ?

Comment: The statement is false unless the characteristic polynomial $f_A(x)$ has double roots.

Comment: @achillehui even if it has double roots, the result is not guaranteed.

Comment: For the question about $A^{-1}$, $A$ invertible implies $a_0 \ne 0$ and

$$\begin{array}{rcrcl}
a_0 I_n + a_1 A + \cdots + A^{n} = 0
& \iff & -a_0 I_n &=& A ( a_1 I_n + \cdots + A^{n-1} )\\
& \implies & A^{-1} &=& -\frac{1}{a_0}\left(a_1 I_n + \cdots + A^{n-1} \right)
\end{array}$$

Comment: @TZakrevskiy what I mean is "the statement is 'always' false unless ..."

Comment: @achillehui didn't doubt that for a second. I added my comment to give a more accurate description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$A\in M_{1\times1}(\Bbb R),\quad A=(1),$$
an invertible matrix. Its characteristic polynomial writes $p_A(x)=1-x$, i.e. $a_0=1$, $a_1=-1$. Apparently, for such a matrix this assertion is false: indeed, if we take $i<n$, then we are forced to take $i=0$, but $a_0\ne0$.

**edit: the solution of your exercise**

$A$ is invertible, hence $a_0\ne 0$. Therefore, by Cayley-Hamilton we get $$-a_0I = a_1A+a_2A^2+\dots a_{n-1}A^{n-1} + (-1)^nA^n.$$
Multiply both part of the above formula by $-\frac{1}{a_0}A^{-1}$ to get
$$A^{-1} = -\frac{1}{a_0} \left(a_1I +a_2A +\dots a_{n-1}A^{n-2} + (-1)^nA^{n-1}\right),$$and, therefore, indeed $$A^{-1}\in span(I,A,A^2,\ldots,A^{n-1}).$$

Comment: Thank you. Why the $(-1)^n$ at $(-1)^nA^n$?

Comment: @Elimination this factor  is there if your definition of the characteristic polynomial is $p_A(x)=\det (A-xI)$. If your definition is $p_A(x)=\det (xI-A)$, then you don't have $(-1)^n$.